# How to run pip from different versions of python using the python command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm now currently using Python on Ubuntu 15.10.

But in my OS, I have many different python versions installed:

- Python (2.7.9)
- Python3 (3.4.3)
- Python3.5
- PyPy

So, it got messy with the versions of the packages in different environments. For example, if I run:

```
pip3 install django
```

But in fact, I cannot import django inside `python3.5`.

Is there any efficient way to call the correct version of `pip`?

Note:
*Don't suggest that I use virtualenv, I know about it and am seeking another solution.*

Comment: Why are you not using virtualenv? It was made to solve this exact problem.

Comment: Run `pip3 -V` and see where it points to. You should also have a `pip3.5` for `Py3.5`.

Comment: @OdraEncoded: Thank you, I've got the answer myself.

Comment: Didn't, you might want to fix the link in your answer though.

Comment: Thank you, I've change the link to a properer section.

Comment: virtuaenv with mkvirtualenv will be better, workon my_djanoapp1, workon mydjanoapp2 like this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Finally I found the solution myself, see the Docs:

https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html?highlight=pip#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel

Just call:

```
pythonXX -m pip install SomePackage
```

That would work separately for each version of installed python.

Also, according to the docs, if we want to do the same thing in windows, the command is a bit different:

```
py -2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
py -2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
py -3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
py -3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
```

Comment: windows: `py -3 -m pip install SomePackage` install the latest 3 version in 64 `py -3.6-32 -m pip install SomePackage` install the module on the 32 bytes version

Comment: Actually, because pip is python script, it is interpreted by python, so it also works well without option '-m', like `pythonXX /usr/bin/pip install <somepackage>`, if you don't know the path of `pip`, use `which` to find it, like this ``pythonXX `which pip` install <somepackage>``

Comment: @Bruce that defeats the whole point of not having to remember different pip versions and automatically matching pip to python by using `-m pip` in a call to the desired python version

Comment: @Bananach No it doesn't. Because you also don't need to remember the pip version. What you are using is `/usr/bin/pip` or `which pip`. There is no version within it.

Answer (score 5):

How about using [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv)?

You can switch the version.

```
$ pyenv install 2.7.X
$ pyenv install 3.5.X
$ pyenv local 2.7.X
$ pyenv global 3.5.X
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me:

```
sudo python2.7 -m pip install [package name]
```

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks so much

Comment: It's not good practice to `sudo pip install` as this clobbers your distribution's Python dependencies on Linux.

Comment: Clobbers? Otherwise agree use of sudo should be limited.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using anaconda?

If you use `conda`, you can easily create/manage virtual env. For example, if you have `root` env python 3.4 and `py27` env for python 2.7, you can easily switch between them use command `source activate [env]`

```
source activate py27
conda install SomePackage
```

Comment: I find that conda and virtual environments work well together. I have multiple versions of python installed in conda environments switch to the one I want then use 'python -m venv ./venv' which installs the python version for the project. Then deactivate the conda environment and run with the new 'venv' for package installations with 'pip' works well so far.