# How can I make pip to install to python 3.64 directory, instead of 2.7

Tags: python, pip, installation

I was trying to install a package from pip but I have gotten that message:

> RuntimeError: aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+

I have installed python 3.64 but it still gives me that error
Thanks!

Comment: try using `pip3`.

Comment: hey, what do you mean by that?
i tried ruining it by cmd and it gave me error 
and when i try from the folder it almost instantly closes                                                                       thanks

Comment: It is common to have `pip` for`python 3` named `pip3`. So you would write `pip3 install aiohttp`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run pip of different version of python using python command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803040/how-to-run-pip-of-different-version-of-python-using-python-command)

Answer (score 1):

To make sure to use the pip version that comes with your python version use:

```
python -m pip install aiohttp
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install aiohttp
```

That is what `-m` does:

> -m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)

You should check your Python version first:

```
python --version
Python 3.6.4
```