# How to install modules in Python 2.7 insted of Python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip

I have two versions of Python in my laptop. Python 2.7 and Python 3.6. If install a module this is installed only in Python 3.6.

I would like to install modules in Python 2.7 through pip but I don't know how to do it.

I want to install right now GDAL and Fiona for Python 2.7 in Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: use `pip2 install ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run pip of different version of python using python command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803040/how-to-run-pip-of-different-version-of-python-using-python-command)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Python 2.7 is well installed on your system, you should have `python2` and/or `python2.7` commands and you could run the following:

```
python2.7 -m pip install <your-packages>
```

To make sure you are running the correct python version, you can use `python2.7 --version`

Comment: It's py -2.7 -m pip install

Answer (score 1):

Better use virtual environment for this.
Follow this link https://realpython.com/blog/python/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

You can set python version to use in virtual env using

```
virtualenv -p path/to/python2.7 env_name
```

Activate this env using `. env_name/bin/activate` then,

Use `pip install package_name` to install libraries inside virtual environment