# Executable scripts installed via `pip` of different Python versions

Tags: python, pip, command-line-interface

To my knowledge, `pip` can install both packages and executable scripts, in latter case it creates a command-line wrapper so we can run the package from the command-line.

Let's say I  have different versions of Python installed on my machine, such as `python3.10` and `python3.11`. If I install a script, say `pytest`, to `python3.11` by running `python3.11 -m pip install pytest`, I can then invoke command `pytest` from the command line:

```bash
$ pytest --version
pytest 7.4.0
```

Now, I decide to install `pytest` to `python3.10` as well using  `python3.10 -m pip install pytest`. With pytest installed in both versions of Python, if I run `pytest` in command line, how do I know which `pytest` will be invoked? Is there a way to specify and invoke `pytest` of a particular version as opposed to the other?

As an aside, `pytest` here could be any other script that could be installed via `pip`.

Comment: pytest version doesn't have anything to do with python version. You will just have one version of pytest after running both commands.
A better option is to use virtual environments (https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) to isolate different versions of python software and the packages/libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing `pytest` (or any pip package) without explicitly specifying a Python version, will utilize the default Python version configured on your system depending on your `$PATH`.

Assuming Python 3.11 is your default version, running

```bash
pytest --version
```

is the same as

```bash
python -m pytest --version
python3.11 -m pytest --version
```

To run `pytest` from another installed Python version just run

```bash
python3.10 -m pytest --version
```

Comment: I have two follow-up questions: 1. If I use `pyenv` to switch to another version of Python and run `pytest`, which version will get invoked? 2. what happen when I run `pytest` in a virtual environment?

Comment: If you use `pyenv` to switch to 3.9 for example, then  `$HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.9/bin/python3.9` will be your new executable. Same with virtual envs, they both override the default python executable from `$PATH` that is normally located in `/usr/bin/python`. You can always look for the current python executable with `which python`

Comment: But the question is not about `python` executable, it's the command line tool installed as Python package such as `pytest`.

Comment: If you activate a virtual env you see `venv/bin` added to `$PATH`. If you look at the content of `venv/bin/pytest` you see a shebang like `#!/venv/bin/python3.9`. That's what determines the Python version.
`pyenv` does a lot, please look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/52060867/22257868