# How install python packages when mulitple python versions are installed in Ubuntu system?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I have python 2.7.12 as default and python 2.7.14.

If I try to install python packages using pip command it will be installed in default package.

How can I install python packages in 2.7.14?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run pip of different version of python using python command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803040/how-to-run-pip-of-different-version-of-python-using-python-command)