# Python packages installing in the wrong folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I am attempting to use Anaconda and running into issues with packages installing in the wrong folders (because I have multiple versions of python installed, which cannot be removed). How do I correctly get new packages installing to the anaconda3 python version?

For example:

```
pip3 install praw <-- installs to python2.7 folder

$ python -m site --user-site
/home/king/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

$ python3 -m site --user-site
/home/king/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages


$ conda install praw   <----fails because cant find package
```

Tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803040/how-to-run-pip-of-different-version-of-python-using-python-command):

```
$ python3.6 -m pip install praw
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/king/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/update_checker.py'

$ sudo -H python3.6 -m pip install praw
sudo: python3.6: command not found
```

All my python directories

```
/home/king/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anaconda does not provide pip3, if anaconda is first in your path, use `pip`. Check with

```
which pip
```

To be sure, you are using the `pip` that corresponds to your `python`, use:

```
python -m pip install ...
```

Edit: Looks like you messed up file permissions of your anaconda install. Maybe by using sudo to install something.
To fix, you could do:

```
sudo chown -R king:king /home/king/anaconda3
```

and don't use sudo again to do stuff with the anaconda install in your home.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, it's highly recommanded to install Anaconda to `/opt` in order to be used by all users (avoid permission problem)

Try to see witch python you use (Anaconda or Native Python) to see with pip you use:

```
 which python
```

if you find that python you use is on `/usr/local/lib` that mean you use the native one,  so tou have to export the `Anaconda/bin` to you environment variable to use Anaconda python. and then you can use pip to install your package:

```
pip install praw
```