# Link pip installed libraries to python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, pip

I have 3 python versions installed: default mac python 2.7, brew python2.7 and brew python3, but my pip libraries are not being linked to anyone.

```
user$ which python
/usr/bin/python
user$ which python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7
user$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
user$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
user$ which pip2
/usr/local/bin/pip2
```

How can I link the pip installed libraries to python and python2.7 commands?

Comment: You would generally use `/usr/bin/python2.7 -m pip install foo` for version 2.7, etc.

Comment: Why don't you separate environments with Virtualenv? You can manipulate the versions and the separate package, use `brew install pyenv` to install. Then go to `pyenv install + version`  use  `pyenv --help` to help you.

Comment: I gave up on Homebrew python, and also recommend pyenv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run pip of different version of python using python command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803040/how-to-run-pip-of-different-version-of-python-using-python-command)